# Issues in configuring OpenVSwitch on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, ssh, openstack

I'm using OpenStack to help me virtualize my infrastructure.
You can see how my topology looks like --> [My topology in OpenStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPNnF.jpg)

I face issues in configuring the 2 switches.
Here is what I have done (I'm in sudo mode) :

1. Installing openvswitch paquets :

   ```
   apt-get install openvswitch-switch
   ```
2. Creating a bridge named br0 :

   ```
   ovs-vsctl add-br br0
   ```
3. Turn up mybridge interface :

   ```
   ifconfig br0 up
   ```
4. Add the physical interface ens4 to the bridge (I'm connecting through the switch via SSH using the interface ens3) :

   ```
   ovs-vsctl add-port br0 ens4
   ```
5. Remove ens4's IP addressing :

   ```
   ifconfig ens4 0
   ```
6. Add to br0 the former ens4's IP adressing (I take the switch 1 for instance) :

   ```
   ifconfig br0 192.168.1.18
   ```
7. Add a default gateway in the routing table :

   ```
   route add default gw 192.168.1.1 br0
   ```

Unfortunately, after all those steps, I'm still unable to ping from Host_1 (whose IP address is 192.168.1.12) to my Switch_1 (whose IP address is 192.168.1.18, the IP address 192.168.0.30 is used for configuring the Switch via SSH connection) and vice-versa.

Any ideas ?
Thank you in advance

P.S. : If the image is not readable, please tell me, I'll make a new one.

Comment: Maybe newer builds of ovs on ubuntu 16.04 are expecting nmcli, not ifconfig? I believe this version switched network utilities.